# Hide and show plot based on two actionButtons in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the shiny app below which initially should be blank. When I press `"Show plot"` the plot should be displayed and when I press `"Hide Plot"` the plot should be hidden.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("showplot",
                   "Show plot"),
      actionButton("hideplot",
                   "Hide plot")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "car_plot")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  hidePlot <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  showPlot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  
  
  observeEvent(input$hideplot, {
    hidePlot(TRUE) 
  })
  observeEvent(input$showplot, {
    showPlot(TRUE) 
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderPlot({
    if (hidePlot()){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else if (showPlot()){
      plot(cars)
    }
      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your reactive values are set to `TRUE` once you press a button but then they are never set back to `FALSE`.

Comment: That's perhaps doable in a similar way but this would be easier with the `hide` and `show`  functions of the 'shinyjs' package.

Comment: Mmh no, in fact it's easy: use only one Boolean reactive value, `hidePlot` or `showPlot`, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only `hidePlot`:

```
  observeEvent(input$hideplot, {
    hidePlot(TRUE) 
  })
  observeEvent(input$showplot, {
    hidePlot(FALSE) 
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderPlot({
    if (hidePlot()){
      return(NULL)
    }
    else {
      plot(cars)
    }
  })
```

Maybe this other way as well:

```
  observeEvent(input$showplot, {
    showPlot(TRUE) 
  })
  observeEvent(input$hideplot, {
    showPlot(FALSE) 
  })
  
  output$car_plot <- renderPlot({
    req(showPlot())
    plot(cars)
  })
```